# rails user input with <script>, stored, and displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an application that collect user input and store to DB and show back to user.

One user entered "alert(1)" into the name field and saved it into DB.

Whenever the name is displayed, the page will be broken.

[image]

I know how to fix that input only with validation for input, and h() for output.

However, I have so many input fields and so many outputs that accept users' text.

Is there any simple way to prevent this happening(i.e. overriding params method, etc)?

I also want to know how you expert guys are dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As of Rails 3, my understanding was that embedded ruby code was html escaped by default. You don't need to use `h()` to make it that way. That is, if you use `<%= "<script>a=1/0;</script>" %>` in a view, the string is going to be made html safe, and so the script doesn't execute. You would have to specifically use `raw()` or something similar to avoid it - which you should naturally not do unless you're really confident about the contents.

Answer (score 0):

For output, Rails 3 automatically html-encode all text unless I use raw() method.

For input, How about making a common validator and apply to all fields that are text or string? Is it desirable?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validator.html

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    record.class.columns.each do |c|
        if c.type==:text || c.type == :string
            record.errors.add c.type, "script tag is not allowed" if c[/<script[^>]*>/]
        end
    end
  end
end
```